# Using a Slider to manipulate a Plot

Tags: plotting, dynamic

Why does this work (displays the curve):

```
Graphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]
```

and this doesn't (no curve)

```
Graphics[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}], {Slider[a, 0, 4]}]
```

?

I would like to work without `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't work for a few reasons:

- The syntax for `Slider` is not correct. It should be `Slider[a, {0, 4}]`
- The variable `a` needs to by `Dynamic` so that it is updated when you move the slider.
- `Slider` is not a graphics primitive.

Additionally, you don't need the `Graphics` and it is a good idea to localize the dynamic variable using `DynamicModule`. I would suggest something like:

```
DynamicModule[{a}, 
    Column[{
        Dynamic@Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}], 
        Slider[Dynamic@a, {0, 4}]
    }]
]
```

[image]

You need to set `PlotRange` so that the figure doesn't jump around when you move the slider.

Comment: Thanks for the correction notes to Edit.

Comment: And thanks for the suggested solution. The reason I THOUGHT I need graphics is that I need to find the mouse position using" MousePosition" in the graphics coordinates. But I might be worng. Not sure how to do it.

Comment: You probably also want to include a `PlotRange` option in `Plot`, because otherwise the x-axis jumps around as you move the slider (and the y-axis minimum and maximum change as well).

Answer (score 6):

You can make the slider to appear as part of the plot:

```
Overlay[{
  Dynamic@Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1, 1}},Frame -> True],
  Panel@VerticalSlider[Dynamic[a], {1, 9}, ImageSize -> {15, 60}]
  }, All, 2, Alignment -> {.9, .8}]
```

[image]

And even develop something more elaborate like this:

```
Overlay[{
  Dynamic@Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick],
  Framed[Row[{Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {1, 9}}, 
      Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, 
      FrameTicks -> {None, Range[9]}, ImageSize -> 20],
     VerticalSlider[Dynamic[a], {1, 9}, ImageSize -> {20, 95}, 
      Appearance -> "LeftArrow"]
     }], FrameMargins -> 0, 
   Background -> Directive[Black, Opacity[.2]], RoundingRadius -> 6]
  }, All, 2, Alignment -> {.9, .8}]
```

[image]