# Plotting fourrier series generated from sum of sine functions

Tags: plotting, functions, summation, fourier-analysis

I'm using *Mathematica* 11.0.1.0 (Student) on macbook. I'm trying to plot a basic square wave function. The sum function return the results of sine function series, I could not see anything from plotting the result.

The only way I could get the plotting to work is to copy the result as plain text, then re-enter it in the Plot function.

Can anyone help identifying where I went wrong, and how I could modify so that the plot can be generated correctly?

For easy copy-and-paste:

```
{Manipulate[IntegerPart[t], {t, 1, 51, 2}, LocalizeVariables -> False], Dynamic[t]}

y = Dynamic[Sum[(6/Pi)*(1/k)*Sin[(k) x], {k, 1, t, 2}]]

Plot[y, {x, 0, 6 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Method I**

Adopting @R.M. approach from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/using-a-slider-to-manipulate-a-plot)

```
DynamicModule[{t}, Column[{Dynamic@Plot[Sum[(6/Pi)*(1/k)*Sin[(k) x], {k, 1, t, 2}], 
                   {x, 0, 6*Pi}, , PlotStyle -> Red], Slider[Dynamic@t, {1, 51, 2}]}]]
```

[image]

**Method II**

The simplest way is to use `Manipulate`,

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sum[(6/Pi)*(1/k)*Sin[(k) x], {k, 1, t, 2}], {x, 0, 6 Pi}], {t, 1, 51}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
{Manipulate[IntegerPart[t], {t, 1, 51, 2}, 
  LocalizeVariables -> False], Dynamic[t]}
Dynamic[y = Sum[(6/Pi)*(1/k)*Sin[(k) x], {k, 1, t, 2}]]
Dynamic[Plot[y, {x, 0, 6 Pi}]]
```

Out:
[image]